# Using multer to store pdf in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, backend, multer

I am trying to store a pdf file in a server using multer and angular. I´ve done this in my HTML . In my controller always prints "VEIO PARA NAO EXISTE FICHEIRO".What am I doing wrong? Is it a issue with the backend or the frontend? Is accept wrong in the HTML?

```
<div *ngIf="request.dataExame && !request.resultado">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>Resultado</h2>
      <p>Inserir Resultado</p>

      <input
        type="radio"
        [(ngModel)]="requestData.resultado"
        value="Negativo"
        name="negativo"
      />
      Negativo
      <input
        type="radio"
        [(ngModel)]="requestData.resultado"
        value="Positivo"
        name="positivo"
      />
      Positivo

      <br />
      <br />

      <input
        type="file"
        id="pdf"
        name="pdf"
        accept=".pdf"
        [(ngModel)]="requestData.pdf"
      />
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="setResult()">
        Confirmar resultado
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And this is what I´ve done in my backend

```
  if (req.file != undefined) {
        console.log("EXISTE FICHEIRO");

        const oldRequest = await Request.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.requestId,
          {
            resultado: req.body.resultado,
            estadoPedido: "Concluído",
            prioridade: 0,
            pdf: `/pdfs/${req.file.filename}`,
          },
          {
            runValidators: true,
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log("VEIO PARA NAO EXISTE FICHEIRO");
        const oldRequest = await Request.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.requestId,
          {
            resultado: req.body.resultado,
            estadoPedido: "Concluído",
            prioridade: 0,
          },
          {
            runValidators: true,
          }
        );
      }
```

This is my route:

```
router.put(
  "/request/:requestId/setResult",
  authController.verifyToken,
  authController.verifyRoleTechnical,
  upload.single("pdf"),
  requestController.setExameResult
);
```

This is my ts file:

```
export class RequestDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() requestData: any = { dataExame: '', resultado: '', pdf: '' };
  request: Request;
  paciente: any;
  error: any;

  constructor(
    public rest: RestService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  setResult() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    let dataResultObject: any = null;
    dataResultObject = {
      resultado: this.requestData.resultado,
      pdf: this.requestData.pdf,
    };
    console.log('RESULTADO DO PEDIDO:', this.requestData);
    this.rest.setRequestResult(id, dataResultObject).subscribe(
      (result) => {},
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On your controller, you present to us `.setExameResult`, but you are referencing to `.scheduleExam`. Is there, maybe a typo when you copy-paste here or it is the real code?

Comment: typo. I will update my answer

Comment: What is the exact error that you get on your console ("error 500" is rather vague to identify what the problem is)

Comment: updated my question. I found that my problem is that there is never req.file

Comment: Have you check that the file is being sent in Angular? Because in the backend you cannot access it until multer has processed it. Also, which is your configuration and initialization of multer?